# QModelIndexList returned by selectedIndexes() is always empty

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I have a `QTableView` inside a `QTabWidget`where i enter new row with 6 columns everytime i press a button. Out of 6 columns, 3 columns have `QPushButton` set on them. I need the row number of the clicked button from the `QTableView`. I have connected the `QPushButton` clicked signal to my slot `clickedIndex()`

This is how i am trying to get the row index of the clicked button but the list is empty.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
   ui->setupUi(this);

   m_view = new QTableView(this);
   m_model = new QStandardItemModel(m_view);
   m_model->setColumnCount(6);

   m_view->setModel(m_model);
   m_model->insertRow(0);

   QPushButton* button = new QPushButton(this);
   button->setText("Click");

   m_view->setIndexWidget(m_model->index(0, 2), button);

   m_model->insertRow(1);

   QPushButton* button1 = new QPushButton(this);
   button1->setText("Click");

   m_view->setIndexWidget(m_model->index(1, 3), button1);

   connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::tableViewClicked);
   connect(button1, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::tableViewClicked);

   setCentralWidget(m_view);
}


MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}



QModelIndex MainWindow::tableViewClicked()
{
    //get the list of currently selected indexes from the model
    QModelIndexList indexList = m_view->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes();

    if (!indexList.isEmpty())
    {
        qDebug() << indexList.front().row(); //prints 0 all the time

        //usually the list should contain only one index at a time
        return indexList.front();
    }
}
```

Here is the header:

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QModelIndex>
#include <QTableView>
#include <QStandardItemModel>

namespace Ui
{
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit MainWindow(QWidget* parent = 0);
        ~MainWindow();

    public slots:

        QModelIndex tableViewClicked();

    private:
        Ui::MainWindow* ui;
        QTableView* m_view;
        QStandardItemModel* m_model;
};
```

I also tried connecting `pressed` signal from `QTableView` but the slot is never called.

```
connect(m_ui->tableView, &QTableView::pressed, this, &TabView::clickedIndex);
```

I believe if there is a `QWidget` on one of the cells in a `QTableView` model the slot is never called. When i click on cells which do not carry a button the connection works.

**I need:**

I just need the `QModelIndex` to the clicked button in the model.

Note: i am using Qt 5.7.1 and i have found some bug reports related to selectedIndexes() like [this](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-611)

Is there a workaround for this?

**EDIT:** In my code the `QModelIndexList` itself is empty.

Comment: I'm not sure but I don't think that clicking on the `QPushButton` will select the underlying row too. But I may be wrong. If you want quick and useful answers, please consider providing a minimal and reproducible example.

Comment: @Fareanor as you suggested i have aaded a MVCE. I also believe the clicking on `QPushButton`will not select the underlying row. The above code prints 0 all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a way to do what you are wanting to do.

```
connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [this, button, view] {
  qDebug() << view->indexAt(button->pos()).row();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a "clicked"-Signal from your TableView. 
To get the index, you can use the following Code:

```
connect(m_ui->tableView, SIGNAL(clicked(QModelIndex)), this, 
SLOT(slotClicked(QModelIndex)));
```

The Slot in the header-File:

```
void slotCLicked(const QModelIndex &index);


void XY::slotClicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    qDebug() << index;
}
```

Comment: `pressed`and `clicked` only works on cells that doesn't contain a widget.This doesn't work for me.